# Demon Hunter AoE damage leveling build (60-70)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

With the new expansion I started to play my Demon Hunter again. Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea of how to play it right because the last 3 months I only played the IWillJustRightclickAndWhirlwindThroughEverythingGainingParagonExperienceLikeCrazy**Barbarian**.

So I kind of forgot how to use a resource besides rage and thus I really struggle with the Hatred costs of the Demon Hunter.

[This is my current build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#bPldSO!beT!YcZbZZ) and I feel like I can't kill monsters quick enough.

What I need is a build that has very good AoE damage while not losing too much survivability and single target damage.

Comment: Demon hunters are intrinsically much more glasscannony then the tanky barbarians though, so you'll always have less survavibility.

Comment: You should check out strafe + night stalker + preparation/punishment build. Very similar to the resource free barbarian builds (now removed). The build requires quite a bit of hatred gen and crit but it is fun IMO.

Comment: I have enjoyed using Cluster Arrow: Loaded for Bear, however that is severly boosted by finding a Cindercoat armor for the -30% cost. Prior to getting my Cindercoat I was using Multishot with the first rune. Cluster Arrow gives you a lot of burst damage which allows you to burst and then kite (I play on HC so that is an added benefit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is my current build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#RPTjkO!ceT!ZcZYab) (focused around having [Kridershot](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/kridershot))

This build is centered around kiting your targets because of slow and increased damage to slowed targets. As long as you keep Marked for death up, you will have a generally very good hatred management. Shadow power and vengenance give you the health regen you need to survive or if you get caught in a corner they can help to bail you out.

The elemental arrows hit for between 500-700k and Cluster arrows hits for 1.8 million.

The only problem I have with it is when the elemental arrow splits off, it might hit a treasure goblin that isn't on the screen and starts its timer far too early.

Edit: After replacing the bow that caused elemental arrows to generate hatred it was difficult to maintain, even with Marked for Death. [This build is slightly modified because of the new weapon](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#aRTjkO!ceT!aZZYab)